# Is the derived group of the G(F) perfect

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected reductive group defined over a finite field  $F$ of characteristic $> 3$. Is it true that the commutator group of $G(F)$ is perfect? This is true if $G$ is assumed to be semisimple.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could explain in your question, why this is true if G is assumeג semisimple and simply connected, with references. Why do you assume that ${\rm char}(F)>3$ ?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven for tori the derived subgroup is trivial, which is definitely a perfect group. It is also true that the derived subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ is the perfect group $\mathrm{SL}_n(K)$ (except for $n=2$, $|K|=2,3$)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ssc}{\text{sc}}
\newcommand{\der}{\text{der}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}$**Yes,** this is true for a reductive $F$-group $G$, if
for the  *simply connected semisimple* $F$-group $G^\ssc$, see below,
the group of $F$-points $G^\ssc(F)$ is perfect,
that is, the derived group $G^\ssc(F)^\der$ coincides with $G^\ssc(F)$.

> **Theorem.** Let $G$ be a (connected) reductive group over a field $F$.
> Let $G^\ssc$ denote the universal cover of the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ of $G$.
> Consider Deligne's homomorphism
> $$\rho\colon\, G^\ssc\twoheadrightarrow [G,G]\hookrightarrow G.$$
> If the group  $G^\ssc(F)$ is perfect, then $G(F)^\der=\rho\bigl(G^\ssc(F)\bigr)$, and hence $G(F)^\der$ is perfect as well.

*Proof.*
Consider the regular maps of $F$-varieties
\begin{align*}
\varkappa&\colon G\times G\to G,\qquad (x,y)\mapsto xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\\
\varkappa^\ssc&\colon G^\ssc\times G^\ssc\to G^\ssc,\quad (x,y)\mapsto xyx^{-1}y^{-1}.
\end{align*}
By definition,
\begin{align*}
G(F)^\der&=\bigl\langle\varkappa\bigl(G(F)\times G(F)\bigr)\bigr\rangle,\\
G^\ssc(F)^\der&=\bigl\langle\varkappa^\ssc\bigl(G^\ssc(F)\times G^\ssc(F)\bigr)\bigr\rangle,
\end{align*}
where $\langle S \rangle$ denotes the subgroup generated by a set $S$.
Deligne observed that $\varkappa$ factors via $G^\ssc$,
that is, there exists a regular map
$$\widetilde\varkappa\colon G\times G\to G^\ssc$$
such that
$$\varkappa=\rho\circ\widetilde\varkappa\colon\, G\times G\,\to\, G^\ssc\,\to\, G.$$
It follows that
$\im\varkappa_F\subseteq \im\rho_F$, where we use the subscript $_F$ to denote
maps on $F$-points, for instance, $\rho_F\colon G^\ssc(F)\to G(F)$.
Therefore,
\begin{align}\tag{1}\label{1}
G(F)^\der=\langle\im \varkappa_F\rangle\subseteq\langle\im\rho_F\rangle=\rho\bigl(G^\ssc(F)\bigr).
\end{align}

Moreover, we have
$$\widetilde\varkappa\circ(\rho\times\rho)=\varkappa^\ssc\colon\ G^\ssc\times G^\ssc\ \to\  G\times G\ \to\  G^\ssc$$
and
$$\rho\circ\widetilde\varkappa\circ(\rho\times \rho)=\rho\circ\varkappa^\ssc\colon\, G^\ssc\times G^\ssc\to G\times G\to G^\ssc\to G.$$
We see that
\begin{align*}
\im\varkappa_F=\im(\rho\circ\widetilde\varkappa)_F\supseteq\im&\bigl(\rho\circ\widetilde\varkappa\circ(\rho\times \rho)\bigr)_F\\
    &=\im(\rho\circ\varkappa^\ssc)_F=\rho(\im \varkappa^\ssc_F),
\end{align*}
whence
\begin{align}\tag{2}\label{2}
G(F)^\der=\langle\im\varkappa_F\rangle\supseteq\rho\langle\im\varkappa^\ssc_F\rangle= \rho \bigl(G^\ssc(F)^\der\bigr).
\end{align}

From \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} we obtain that
\begin{align}\tag{3}\label{3}
\rho\bigl(G^\ssc(F)^\der\bigr)\subseteq G(F)^\der\subseteq \rho\bigl(G^\ssc(F)\bigr).
\end{align}

Now assume that $G^\ssc(F)$ is perfect. Thus means that
$$G^\ssc(F)^\der=G^\ssc(F),\quad\text{whence}\quad  \rho\bigl(G^\ssc(F)^\der\bigr)=\rho\bigl(G^\ssc(F)\bigr),$$
and we obtain from \eqref{3} that $G(F)^\der=\rho\bigl(G^\ssc(F)\bigr)$.
Since $G^\ssc(F)$ is perfect, so is $\rho\bigl(G^\ssc(F)\bigr)$. Thus $G(F)^\der$ is perfect, as required.

Comment: How common is it that $G^\text{sc}(F)$ is perfect?  (E.g., do you know any nice sufficient conditions?)

Comment: TeX note: `\newcommand{\im}{{\rm im\,}}` spaces worse than `\DeclareMathOperator\im{im}`; compare ${\rm im\,}(\rho)$ (the first) to $\operatorname{im}(\rho)$ (the second). MathJax note: *unlike* TeX, MathJax does not aggressively swallow newlines, so the dollar sign that ends the 'preamble' must be immediately followed by the text to avoid a post that starts with blank lines.  *Like* TeX, MathJax obeys `\label`+`\eqref`, so you can get nice clickable references to go with `\tag`s.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: (You also probably want `&=` or `={}&` rather than just `=&` in your `{align}` environments, to avoid collapsing spaces, like ${=}{\operatorname{im}}$ as opposed to $=\operatorname{im}$.  However, I was not sure if this was a stylistic choice, so I did not edit it.)

Comment: @LSpice: See the book by Platonov and Rapinchuk, Section 7.2: The Kneser-Tits conjecture.

Comment: @LSpice: Thanks for the TeXnical comments!

Comment: Thanks for the [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428542/is-the-derived-group-of-the-gf-perfect/428626#comment1102506_428626); I hadn't thought of the connection to KT.  Is the observation that $\varkappa$ factors through $G^\text{sc} \to G$ really due to Deligne?  It seems like something that would have been observed in the very first days of the theory of Lie groups, even before the introduction of algebraic groups.

Comment: @LSpice: I found it in Deligne, "Varietes de Shimura: interpretation modulaire..." in the Corvallis proceedings, Part 2, pages 262-263. The point is that $G$ is reductive, while in the classical works, $G$ was semisimple. The notion of a reductive group appears only in the theory of *algebraic* groups, not *Lie* groups.

Comment: The source of Deligne's homomorphism should be $G^{sc}$?

Comment: @WilberdvanderKallen: Yes, sure. Corrected.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1102576), I thought that a reductive Lie group could be described as one with an embedding into $\operatorname{GL}_n$ whose image is stable under inverse transpose?  Or, of course, it can simply be described as a central quotient of a torus and a semisimple (or even simply connected) group (which makes it particularly clear that the commutator factors through the simply connected cover).  But maybe you mean that reductive groups *didn't* appear, not that they *couldn't* appear.  Anyway, I wasn't arguing, just surprised!